# Positioning title in the center of a custom Chrome window

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've started learning WPF a few days ago. Now, I've built a custom window, because of the defaults one title position and color. I've made a grid that consists of tree custom templated buttons and a text block. The problem is that I can't position the title in the center of a window, but only in the center of the given cell. Is there any relatively easy approach to fix this so that window stays resizeable? The code is very simple as you can imagine.

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Title-->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <!--Window buttons-->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Here is the image.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwOGy.png]

Comment: I've added it, but I don't think the code could help you, I asked for an approach for these kinds of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Grid.ColumnSpan=2 in the Title control. This means that you are occupying 2 columns. You still need the Grid.Column=0 to let know that you start from column 0.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Title-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <!--Window buttons-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<Grid>
```

Or another way is that do not even use columndefinitions at all, but just put the buttons control with HorizontalAlignment=Right

```
<!-- Parent control of these should be Grid -->
<TextBlock Text="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<StackPanel x:Name="Buttons" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
   ...
</StackPanel>
```

However, either way, beware that you might have collision between your title to the buttons, because you simply ignore the column size.

I would recommend you to stick with what you have made (similar to the pic you posted), or simply change the design not to use centered title, but left aligned title.

Comment: Just in time, I was typing an answer, and you showed up :D